# OCAML - Is element in the list?

Tags: ocaml

let's say we have a list of elements:

```
[(a,b); (c,d); (e,f)]
```

What function would check if element (lets say A, where A=(x,y)) is in the list or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `List.mem` to do the search for a match.

```
let a = (3,4)
List.mem a [(1,2); (3,4); (5,6)]
```

You can also use `List.memq` if you want to check if the two items both reference the same entity in memory.

Comment: Thank you, this really works. I was just wondering if there is any way to write your own function that would check the list the same way, returnig true or false.

Comment: Of course their is, you can check the list module source code if you have questions; it's very readable.

Comment: [One set of sources here.](http://docs.camlcity.org/docs/godipkg/3.12/godi-ocaml/lib/ocaml/std-lib/list.ml)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint on how to write this yourself. The natural way to to process a list is to initially look at the first element, then check the remainder of the list recursively until you have an empty list. For this problem, you could state the algorithm in English as follows:

> If the list is empty then the item is not in the list,
>   else if the first list element equals the item then it is in,
>   else it is the answer to (Is the item in the remainder of the list?)

Now you just need to translate this into OCaml code (using a recursive function).

In general, if you can describe what you want to do in terms of smaller or simpler parts of the problem, then writing the [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) code is straightforward (although you have to be careful the base cases are correct). When using a list or tree-structured data the way to decompose the problem is usually obvious.